# Bokeh gridplot-Tighten layout and outer sidelabels

Tags: python, bokeh

I have some bokeh plots that are arranged in a gridplot. 
[image]

I would like to do two things to improve the presentation:

1. Tighten the layout by removing the space between the subplots. Only the outer ticklabels on the subplots should show.
2. Put in outer sidelabels that will label the subplots.

I want something that looks like this except without any space between the subplots. http://blog.yhat.com/static/img/figures/diamonds_density_facet_grid.png
[image]

Any help would be much appreciated. Here's the code that I have so far.

```
from bokeh.io import gridplot, output_file, show
from bokeh.plotting import figure

output_file("layout.html")

x = list(range(11))
y = x
y1 = [10-i for i in x]
y2 = [abs(i-5) for i in x]

s1 = figure(width=250, height=250, title=None)
s1.circle(x, y, size=10, color="navy", alpha=0.5)

s2 = figure(width=250, height=250, x_range=s1.x_range, y_range=s1.y_range, title=None)
s2.triangle(x, y1, size=10, color="firebrick", alpha=0.5)

s3 = figure(width=250, height=250, x_range=s1.x_range, y_range=s1.y_range, title=None)
s3.square(x, y2, size=10, color="olive", alpha=0.5)

p = gridplot([[s1, None], [s2, s3]])

show(p)
```

Comment: You can turn off the tick marks on one or another plot by using something like: `s3.axis.major_tick_line_color = None` and turn off labels with `s3.axis.major_label_text_font_size ='0pt'`.  As for spacing, it seems like setting the min_border attribute to '0' should work, but that doesn't seem to be working properly right now (is an open [github issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/3563)).  Not really an answer, but hopefully that gets you closer!